# n to many database relationships

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

First of all, I can't imagine this questions not being answered here before but I really tried and couldn't find it, I guess I'm using the wrong wording. I apologize.

I'm doing a database design and on it I have 2 entities:

- Team
- Match

Every match takes part between exactly 2 teams. At first I thought the relationship was a "Many to Many" relationship, so I thought an association table was the correct answer.

But when thinking about it, the relantionship is more like 2 to many, and I think having the columns TeamA and TeamB would make more sense.

I asked a friend and he said the relantionship, being managed by two different columns are actually two 1 to 1 relantionships. Making the 2 columns solution the right one.

What's the correct answer?.

Comment: I'm assuming teams can play multiple matches in which case you have a 1 to many relationship

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Language is your problem here.

In any given Match you'll have two Team instances playing.  A Match will occur at a unique location and start time.

Over the course of a season a Team will play a Schedule, which is a collection of Match instances.

If you agree, a Match is a single pairing of two Teams; Schedule is a collection of Match instances.  A Team will play a unique Schedule.

So I can envision a schema like this:

1. Team table with a primary key.
2. Match table with a primary key and two foreign keys that refer to the Team table, one for each of the two Teams involved.
3. Schedule table with a primary key, foreign key that refers to Team, and many foreign keys that refer to Match instances.  Schedule is 1:1 with Team and 1:many w/ Match.

Comment: I might've condensed my situation too much, yes, a match is just an instance, a game played at a determined time. My question is more of where do I store which 2 teams play in said instance.